# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.xxx.xxx.Email, while initializing kotlin class from java class

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm, noclassdeffounderror

I need to use an existing Kotlin encryption file in a java class. While trying to do that getting `NoClassDefFoundError` Exception. The import statements are proper no issues with that.
If I run this application from intellij its working, but when I run via terminal with `./gradlew clean build` its throwing the error.

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.xxx.xxx.Email
```

Location of java file - src/main/java/com/company/team/project/service

Location of kotlin file - src/main/java/com/company/team/project/service/encryption

Kotlin class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue 
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors 
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor

private const val EMAIL_ENCRYPTION_SECRET = "EMAIL_ENCRYPTION_SECRET"

class Email constructor(emailValue: String) : Comparable<Email> {

    val emailId: String = emailValue
    val encryptedValue = encrypt(emailId)
    val decryptedValue = decrypt(encryptedValue)

    override fun compareTo(other: Email): Int = emailId.compareTo(other.emailId)

    @JsonValue
    override fun toString(): String = emailId

    override fun hashCode(): Int = emailId.hashCode()

    companion object {

        private var aesCipher: TextEncryptor

        init {
            val encryptionKey = System.getenv(EMAIL_ENCRYPTION_SECRET)
            aesCipher = Encryptors.queryableText(encryptionKey, encryptionKey)
        }

        @JsonCreator
        fun of(value: String?): Email? = if (value == null) null else Email(value)

        fun value(e: Email?): String? = e?.emailId

        fun encrypt(plaintextEmail: String): String = "EEA:${aesCipher.encrypt(plaintextEmail)}"

        fun decrypt(encryptedEmail: String): String {
            if (!encryptedEmail.startsWith("EEA:")) {
                throw IllegalArgumentException("Encrypted text does not have expected EEA prefix.")
            }
            val cipherTextWithoutEEA = encryptedEmail.replaceFirst("^EEA:".toRegex(), "")
            return aesCipher.decrypt(cipherTextWithoutEEA)  

          }
     } 
}
```

Java class

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class FindUserData extends TaskHandler<Void> {
--- some codes and other methods ---
   private ExecutionResult doExecute(ExecutionContext<Void> context) {
       --- properly working code ---- 
       Email email = new Email(userData.get().toString());
       String emailId = email.getEncryptedValue();
       log.info(context.format("Found user data: %s", emailId));
       --- Other working code ---
   }
}
```

Comment: Where is the file containing the kotlin class located? In src/main/java/com/xxx/xxx?

Comment: This is location of java file - src/main/java/com/company/team/project/service and the 
location of kotlin file - src/main/java/com/company/team/project/service/encryption